# Does it make sense to query a state with a getter before toggling that state with a setter?

Tags: java, swing

I have a little Swing app that has the following code snippet (it's an inner class). The checkboxes and buttons are `JCheckBox` and `JButton` instances respectively

```java
    private class CheckBoxListener implements ItemListener {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                saveButton.setEnabled(true);
                clearButton.setEnabled(true);
            } else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED &&
                    checkBoxList.stream().noneMatch(AbstractButton::isSelected)) {
                saveButton.setEnabled(false);
                clearButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am wondering whether it makes sense to change, for example, this

```java
saveButton.setEnabled(true);
```

to this

```java
if (!saveButton.isEnabled()) {
    saveButton.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Without the check, I'd say, 90% of the time the setter doesn't do any actual work (the button already has the state being set). On the other hand, setting it blindly may be cheaper that querying that state every time and then setting it if needed. Which approach should I prefer?

Comment: Looks like extra effort for little-to-no gain. Also, don't optimize blindly. Worry about that level of micro-optimization when you have *measured* there's a bottleneck there.

Comment: Before jumping to conclusions you either look at the source code of that setter (maybe it performs the same check anyway) or run a benchmark.

Comment: The better approach depends on the context and your coding style. If your intention is to simply enable the button regardless of its current state, using `saveButton.setEnabled(true);` is cleaner and more direct. It's also a common idiom in programming to set properties directly when you know what you want to set them to.

However, if you're concerned about performance or if you want to make sure you're only making changes to the button's state when necessary, the conditional approach might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference here would be if you want to know if property was changed or not.

JButton.setEnabled() will call JComponent.setEnabled()

which looks like that

```
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        boolean oldEnabled = isEnabled();
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
        firePropertyChange("enabled", oldEnabled, enabled);
        if (enabled != oldEnabled) {
            repaint();
        }
    }
```

firePropertyChange will fire an event which can be listened to etc.

So performance wise checking first if button is enabled would be better but the difference will be minimal

Keep in mind that actual event will be fired only if your new value will be different from old value so better performance would only come from more functions being called and few more if statements in setEnabled vs checking for is enabled beforehand